# Timer tasks using java

Tags: java

I have a requirement that, with in a time duration (suppose it is 50 sec, the time might be dynamic) i have to fetch some data from a server. 
At the same time every  10sec (in between this 30 sec), I have to send some keys to server.

for that iam using below code....but it is not working

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long duration = (50 * 1000);
    do {


       // RESEt request call code goes here..
       /////
       //////
        System.out.println("Rest request");

        java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
        java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
        //Sending key every 10 sec
          RemoteKey.send(PageUp);

        }

        };
        t.schedule(task, 0, (10 * 1000));
// This do while loop will execute 50 sec
    } while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) < duration);

    }
```

Comment: "but it is not working" - can you specify in what way?

Comment: its become an infinite loop

Comment: What's the PageUp parameter? Where does it come from?

Comment: Have a look at the documentation on timers. You'll see that timers will take a task once and run it multiple times. What you do is create a massive amount of timers because your loop doesn't block and thus will continue to create new timers for 50 seconds. So get rid of that loop and use `Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` or something similar instead.

Comment: Not an infinite loop. You loop will end correctly after ~50s but you don't put the loop to sleep. So it keeps starting many, many, many tasks

Comment: @Thomas `schedule` is for singe fire tasks.

Comment: This is a task for a ScheduledExecutorService, which you'll want to shutdown gracefully as soon as the time lapse has expired.

Comment: Why not a infinite loop with a Thread.sleep in it?

Comment: @chris01 why not a **finite** loop with a sleep?

Comment: @Antoniossss right, but that won't block and creating that many timers will cause problems as well. And if there's a need to have repeats then using `scheduleAtFixedRate()` would be the better option than rolling your own loop (in fact rolling your own loop would make using a timer moot).

Comment: Use an ExecutorService.
1. Start the Executor
2. Sleep until "duration"
3. Stop the Executor

Comment: Creating timer in loop is a big "nono" to me

Answer (score 1):

Why not schedule once, and cancel itself?

```
long duration=whatever;

java.util.Timer timer = new java.util.Timer();
        java.util.TimerTask task = new java.util.TimerTask() {
        long t0=System.currentTimeMilis(); // or set it upon scheduling;
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //this will stop the task from executing in future.
         if((System.currentTimeMillis() - t0) >= duration) { this.cancel(); return;}
        // do actual work
          RemoteKey.send(PageUp);
        }
        };

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,initialDelay,delayBetweenActions);
```

More modern approach would be to use `ScheduledExecutorService`.

Comment: here what does this initialDelay means? is it duration?pleaase clarify?

Comment: also where can i also server response fetch operation

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use RxJava and Job Scheduler to schedule the task at particular interval.

For example:

```
Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .doOnNext(n -> performYourtask())
                    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be the optimal approach, using the modern `ScheduledExecutor`
As the timespan of, say 50 seconds, is ruled by the *fetching* operation, and that operation is synchronous, you'll just have to wait for it to end.

```
// Start the executor, scheduling your Runnable Task to run every 10 seconds
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(
        () -> {
            // Send your data
        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

// Fetch data from your Server.
// That's a blocking operation, which, let's say will take 50 seconds

// Stop the Executor as the time is over
executorService.shutdown();
```

The `Executor` can be created via Factory method.

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);          // For multiple, concurrent threads
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(); // For a synchronous "queue"
```